# Can we give read/write access permission for a "field" on Plone formgen Form field in Plone for a specific user?

Tags: python, plone

I wish to create a form using form gen. In this form, based on login permissions like add, edit or view I wish to make a form field's input data editable by a user. Is there any such feature readily available with default Plone without any coding effort? Using Plone 4.1
In other words, some users should not be able to add certain field data, they can only view the default value of that field on the form.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; you want to show an extra field if there is an authenticated user, but hide it if the user is anonymous?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters in short I want to customise the form for inputs from different users with different form field permissions

Comment: @Yuri, any leads on this, please help. Thanx in advance